# Initialising view controller with IBOutlets to custom views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, iboutlet, awakefromnib

I am trying to find a way to initialise a view controller which has IBOutlets to a custom view that I have created in a XIB.

Here is the code where I initialise my class:

```
MyContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [[MyContentViewController alloc] init];
self.pageContent = pageContentViewController;
[pageContentViewController view];
```

MyContentViewController has the following properties:

```
 @interface MyContentViewController : UIViewController

 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MyContentView *topLeftView;
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MyContentView *topRightView;
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MyContentView *bottomLeftView;
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MyContentView *bottomRightView;
```

In MyContentViewController xib I have 4 views which I have set as MyContentView and have hooked the IBOutlet's above to the views in the storyboard.

[image]

The custom view is defined as following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyContentView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *labelView;

 @end
```

However when I run the application, I get the 4 views I have added in the MyContentViewController xib. However none of them display the UILabel from the custom UIView.

I have added the following in MyContentView:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSLog(@"VIEW AWAKE");
}
```

This get printed out so the views are being loaded. However how can I get them to display using the 4 IBOutlets.

Here is a picture of the app running with the view. There is no labels on the 4 views:
[image]

Comment: Hi, you can try that statement:     MyContentViewController *vc = [[MyContentViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YouXib" bundle:nil];

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However it was loading the MyContentView that was the problem. Laser link contained the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your "MyContentView" has a nib of it's own. Loading a custom UIView class which has a nib layout from another nib is a bit more complex.

I think this [blog post](http://blog.yangmeyer.de/ios%20dev/2012/07/09/an-update-on-nested-nib-loading.html) contains the answer

Comment: Thanks. The link did contain the answer.